# What are the highest quality textbooks for learning English grammar?

Tags: discussion, reference

I am a native English speaker, but I think my grasp of grammar is too weak. So, I want to know what textbooks or reference books others deem worthy of using to deepen and broaden their understanding and grasp of English grammar. What do you use and recommend?

Comment: Hi JBR, please see our [meta] for all kinds of resources and references, and welcome to EL&U.

Comment: If you're a beginner of English grammar you need to start off slow. The best quality grammar books will be suitable for speakers who are already comfortable with the terminology, IMO most grammar books are incredibly boring, they're not something you can read from the beginning to end. God knows I've tried. If you want something readable and enjoyable I'd recommend David Crystal.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What good reference works on English are available?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2573/what-good-reference-works-on-english-are-available) CGEL, and McCawley, are mentioned, but are very demanding (and don't always agree). //  BillJ argues that Crystal isn't a grammarian. // Perhaps Collins Cobuild is a starting point ... but don't expect all to agree with its analyses.

Comment: Much depends on whether your aim is to be more confident in your day-to-day use of the language or to get a theoretical appreciation of the grammar: compare the two answers to [this question](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15591), of which yours is essentially a duplicate.